# How to match data between sheets using loops

Tags: vba, excel

okay so the breakdown.

I have 2 sheets. One sheet (order_LVL) has the original data with order numbers going down the rows and "line numbers" with locations integers of that line in the corresponding cells. I'm trying to populate the other sheet (sheet1) with the same order numbers going down the rows, but with the location numbers (1-246) as the column headers (essentailly the values within the cells of order_LVL are becoming the column headers of sheet1). Within the corresponding cells I want to put a "1" if the order_LVL indicates that an order features a line from that location and a "0" if it does not.

This is what I have for populating the data and I keep getting an error saying "object does not support this propety or method" at the line with the If statement"

```
Sub PopulateData()
Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim s2 As Excel.Worksheet
Set s1 = Sheets("Order_LVL")
Set s2 = Sheets("sheet1")
Dim orderrows As Range
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Set orderrows = Range("B2" & Lastrow)
Dim iRow As Variant
For Each iRow In orderrows
Dim j As Variant
    For Each j In s1.Range("Q:DL")
    locationRow = 1
    Dim i As Variant
        For Each i In s2.Range("B1:JE1")
            If s1(iRow, j) = s2(locationRow, i) Then
            s2(iRow, i) = 1 'indicates that this order features a line from this location
            Else: s2(iRow, i) = 0
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
Next iRow
End Sub
```

I'm really new to VBA and help guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: the j loop is going through each cell within the current iRow in Order_LVL and the i loop is going through the location headers in sheet1 to match to the values of the cells in the order_LVL sheet.

Comment: Instead of `SheetVariable(Row, Column)` you need to call the Cells method like so: `SheetVariable.Cells(Row, Column)`

Comment: okay now I'm getting an error at the same line saying "type mismatch". I think it might be because my i, j, and iRow are variants, but i don't know what else i could make them. I thought they needed to be variants for the For Each loop.

Comment: With the way your loops are structured, it is incredibly inefficient.  Instead consider: `For i = 2 to orderrows` and `For j = 2 to Columns("JE").Column`

Comment: And take out the for loop of `iRow in orderrows` that one seems redundant

Comment: but will that match the cell in order_LVL to each column in sheet1? My rationale was that I needed to loop through each order and then within that order I need to loop through each cell in that row to match the value of the cell to each of the column headers in sheet1. I'll try it though.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the repaired code below. Please excuse me I didn't read the business context, (in a bit of a rush), just repaired the syntax problems in your script....

```
Sub PopulateData()
Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim s2 As Worksheet
Dim locationRow As Integer
Set s1 = Sheets("Order_LVL")
Set s2 = Sheets("sheet1")
Dim orderrows As Range
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set orderrows = Range("B2" & Lastrow)
Dim iRow As Integer

For iRow = 1 To orderrows.Rows.Count
Dim cellj As Range
    For Each cellj In s1.Range("Q:DL")
    locationRow = 1
    Dim celli As Range
        For Each celli In s2.Range("B1:JE1")
            If s1.Cells(iRow, cellj.Column).Value = s2.Cells(locationRow, celli.Column).Value Then
            s2.Cells(iRow, celli.Column).Value = 1 'indicates that this order features a line from this location
            Else: s2.Cells(iRow, celli).Value = 0
            End If
        Next celli
    Next cellj
Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: No probs...just a note this line `Else: s2.Cells(iRow, celli).Value = 0`   is supposed to be `Else: s2.Cells(iRow, celli.Column).Value = 0`